# Why getting the wrong day in month using Android Java?

Tags: java, android, date

Where the day today is `Oct 24, 2011` .

but using this code

```
  Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
  int d = currentDate.DAY_OF_MONTH;
```

gives me the date `5`

P.S. the date in emulator settings is `October 24, 2011`

Comment: yep you allways got 5 :)  public final static int DAY_OF_MONTH = 5;

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
 currentDate.DAY_OF_MONTH;
```

is constant which is used internally in Calendar class. To get the current day of  month use

use

```
currentDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

**Update:**

> how to shift the current date 6 days, and get the new day and month value ? 
>       //adding 6 days
>       currentDate.add(Calendar.DATE, 6);

```
//retrieving the month now, note month starts from 0-Jan, 1-Feb
currentDate.get(Calendar.MONTH);
```

Comment: that's it. thanks, I will accept your question soon, another question how to shift the current date 6 days, and get the new day and month value ?

Answer (score 4):

The `DAY_OF_MONTH` field is a constant Integer. Use the method `get` instead:

```
currentDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

You can add for example 6 days using:

```
currentDate.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 6);
```

See also [this page](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html).

Answer (score 0):

## `ZonedDateTime`

The modern way to do this is with the java.time classes.

A [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) represents a moment on the timeline with a resolution of nanoseconds.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z );
int dayOfMonth = zdt.getDayOfMonth();
```

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`.

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (see [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706)).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as `Interval`, `YearWeek`, `YearQuarter`, and more.